# What is the maximum diameter of $N$ steps of a random walk?

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Since probability is quite far away from my daily buisiness, please forgive me if my use of terminology is wrong or the question is too trivial. However, I was not able to find the right keyword to find an answer by googling...  I am even not sure if "random walk" is the right name for what I am going to describe.

Consider a particle which is moving around randomly in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in steps such that in every step its movement is desribed by a draw of a 2D Gaussian distribution with variance $\sigma$. In other words: From position $x_k$ at time $k$ it moves to position $x_{k+1} = x_k + d_k$ where $d_k$ is normally distributed with variance $\sigma$. If the particle starts at
time $0$ at $0$, then the distribution of its position at time $N$ is Gaussian with variance $\sqrt{N}\sigma$, since this is just the addition of $N$ Gaussian random variables which amounts to the $N$-fold convolution of the Gaussian with variance $\sigma$. Am I right on this?

But my question is this: What is the distribution of $\max\{\|x_j - x_k\|\ |\ 1\leq j,k\leq N\}$ and how to you calculate it?

Finally: What is the answer to the same question if unit steps in random directions are taken, i.e. $d_k$ is uniformly distributed on the unit circle?

Pointers to literature are also appreciated.

Comment: Your model is what is known as "Brownian motion".

Comment: This is somewhat closely related to the "maximum drawdown" of a Brownian motion, which has been studied in various forms in the mathematical finance literature. The differences are (a) the Brownian motion is assumed to be observed continuously rather than discretely, as in your model above and (b) the max. drawdown is $\sup_{0 < t \leq T}(\sup_{0< s \leq t} W_s−W_t)$. I'm not sure at the moment if there is an exact closed-form for the distribution you are interested in. Would you be interested in bounds? 

Comment: @cardinal: that's a very good comment, with minor notes that (a) I have ever only found one paper on drawdown distributions and (b) for obvious reasons drawdowns are rarely two-dimensioonal.

Comment: Some references of potential interest: (**1**) W. Feller (1951), The asymptotic distribution of the range of sums of independent random variables, Ann. Math. Stat, vol. 22, no. 3, 427-432 (link: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729589), (**2**) E. Tanre & P. Vallois, Range of Brownian motion with drift (link: http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Etienne.Tanre/…), (**3**) H. He, et al., Double lookbacks (link: http://som.yale.edu/~hh78/lb_9612.pdf) and (**4**) M. Magdon-Ismael, et al, On the maximum drawdown of a Brownian motion, (link: http://www.jstor.org/pss/3215821).

Comment: Those all deal with one-dimensional results, but they may provide a starting point for further exploration. I can't really vouch for any of the last three personally; they're more works that I know of, rather than ones I'm deeply familiar with.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula for the distribution in question, or just its expectation/asymptotics/tail behaviour? In the latter case, bounding by the diameter of Brownian motion would probably give a more tractable problem. I'd be surprised if there is an exact explicit formula for either of the discrete RWs you specified. 

Comment: Thanks so far for the comments and references! I'll check them out. @Igor: Is this also called Brownian motion if it is time discrete? Would it be right to say that the time discrete model is a sampled continuous Brownian motion? Sorry for my ignorance on this topic... 

Comment: @cardinal: Bounds would also be helpful as well as asymptotic results. I briefly went over the papers you linked - as I understood thay all rely in some way on the ordering of the reals and hence, generalization seems not to be straightforward...

Comment: @Dirk: Regarding bounds, it seems that, in particular because the movement in one coordinate is independent of the movement in the other coordinate(s), things can be decoupled in such a way that the one-dimensional results could be brought into play without a tremendous amount of loss. For example
$$
\mathbb P(\max_{i,j} \|X_{i,1}-X_{j,1}\|^2 > \lambda ) \leq \mathbb P(\max_{i,j} \|X_i - X_j\|^2 > \lambda) \leq 2 \mathbb P( \max_{i,j} \|X_{i,1} - X_{j,1}\|^2 > \lambda / 2 )
$$
which are among the crudest bounds imaginable. (Indeed no assumption of independence is made above.)

Comment: @Dirk: In your case, letting $S_1(\lambda) = \mathbb P(\max_{i,j} \|X_{i,1}-X_{j,1}\|^2 > \lambda )$, due to independence, if I am not mistaken, the lower bound can be replaced by $S_1(\lambda)(2-S_1(\lambda))$ and the upper bound by $S_1(\lambda/2)(2-S_1(\lambda/2))$.

Comment: Thanks! Probably I should note that also the expected value would be helpful.

Comment: I think that there is unlikely to be a simple precise answer to this question beyond rough bounds. There is more chance if you consider the limit $N\to\infty$, in which case it reduces to continuous Brownian motion. Even in that case, I don't know if there's any way of solving it other than numerically.

Comment: The distribution of the maximum in the discrete 1-dimensional case is determined precisely in this arXiv paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0506195.pdf .  As noted by cardinal above, the 2-d case can be analyzed within a constant by considering the $x$ and $y$ displacements separately.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, disregard what is below. The LIL gives $\max_{i \le N} |x_i| \approx \sqrt{2 N \log \log N}$ for infinitely many $N$, but for any particular $N$,
$\max_{i \le N} |x_i|$ should be of the order $\sqrt N$.

If you only care about bounds up to a constant factor, then I think you're after the law of the iterated logarithm (LIL). As Cardinal indicated, it's enough to consider the 1-dimensional problem (if you don't care about losing a factor of 2). Moreover,
$$
\max_i|x_i| \le \max_{i,j} |x_i - x_j| \le 2\max_i |x_i|
$$
and so you may as well consider $\max |x_i|$ instead. By the LIL, $\max_{i \le N} |x_i| \sim \sqrt{2 N \log \log N}$ almost surely.

The same argument works if the steps are distributed on the unit circle, since the LIL doesn't require Gaussian variables.

If you want to try to get the sharp constant, there are also multi-dimensional versions of the LIL available. You can search for them on Google; I don't really know that area...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to say more about the co-variance of the $d_k$, in order to make the problem precise.  Also, I assume that you want $d_k$ independent of $d_{\ell}$ for all $k\neq \ell$.
I think with that, you might start to be able to have intuitions about the general shape covered by you walk and therefore start having ideas about the directions (eigenvector) along which to consider the range.  That might then make your problem suitable to one dimensional techniques, maybe even order statistics.

hope this helps.